# Getting all css attributes of a specific class from any css file

Tags: python, css, regex, parsing

Is there any relatively easy way of getting the combined attributes of one class using some sort of parser in python, or do I have to come up with some regex to get it instead ?

```
.container_12, .container_16 {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px
}
.grid_1, .grid_2, .grid_3, .grid_4, .grid_5 {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px
}
.featured_container .container_12 .grid_4 a {
    color: #1d1d1d;
    float: right;
    width: 235px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: 4px solid #141a20;
```

For the above css snippet, if I searched for "container_12" it should return:

```
  {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        width:960px
        color: #1d1d1d;
        float: right;
        width: 235px;
        height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 40px;
        border: 4px solid #141a20;
    }
```

Duplicate attributes are fine, I will use a dictionary to store them afterwards, so it will not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough parser for your CSS:

```
import pyparsing as pp

# punctuation is important during parsing, but just noise afterwords; suppress it
LBRACE, RBRACE = map(pp.Suppress, "{}")

# read a ':' and any following whitespace
COLON = (":" + pp.Empty()).suppress()

obj_ref = pp.Word(".", pp.alphanums+'_') | pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums+'_')
attr_name = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums+'-_')
attr_spec = pp.Group(attr_name("name") + COLON + pp.restOfLine("value"))

# each of your format specifications is one or more comma-delimited lists of obj_refs,
# followed by zero or more attr_specs in {}'s
# using a pp.Dict will auto-define an associative array from the parsed keys and values
spec = pp.Group(pp.delimitedList(obj_ref)[1,...]('refs')
                + LBRACE
                + pp.Dict(attr_spec[...])("attrs")
                + RBRACE)

# the parser will parse 0 or more specs    
parser = spec[...]
```

Parsing your css source:

```
result = parser.parseString(css_source)
print(result.dump())
```

Gives:

```
[['.container_12', '.container_16', [['margin-left', 'auto;'], ['margin-right', 'auto;'], ['width', '960px']]], ['.grid_1', '.grid_2', '.grid_3', '.grid_4', '.grid_5', [['display', 'inline;'], ['float', 'left;'], ['margin-left', '10px;'], ['margin-right', '10px']]], ['.featured_container', '.container_12', '.grid_4', 'a', [['color', '#1d1d1d;'], ['float', 'right;'], ['width', '235px;'], ['height', '40px;'], ['text-align', 'center;'], ['line-height', '40px;'], ['border', '4px solid #141a20;']]]]
[0]:
  ['.container_12', '.container_16', [['margin-left', 'auto;'], ['margin-right', 'auto;'], ['width', '960px']]]
  - attrs: [['margin-left', 'auto;'], ['margin-right', 'auto;'], ['width', '960px']]
    - margin-left: 'auto;'
    - margin-right: 'auto;'
    - width: '960px'
  - refs: ['.container_12', '.container_16']
[1]:
  ['.grid_1', '.grid_2', '.grid_3', '.grid_4', '.grid_5', [['display', 'inline;'], ['float', 'left;'], ['margin-left', '10px;'], ['margin-right', '10px']]]
  - attrs: [['display', 'inline;'], ['float', 'left;'], ['margin-left', '10px;'], ['margin-right', '10px']]
    - display: 'inline;'
    - float: 'left;'
    - margin-left: '10px;'
    - margin-right: '10px'
  - refs: ['.grid_1', '.grid_2', '.grid_3', '.grid_4', '.grid_5']
[2]:
  ['.featured_container', '.container_12', '.grid_4', 'a', [['color', '#1d1d1d;'], ['float', 'right;'], ['width', '235px;'], ['height', '40px;'], ['text-align', 'center;'], ['line-height', '40px;'], ['border', '4px solid #141a20;']]]
  - attrs: [['color', '#1d1d1d;'], ['float', 'right;'], ['width', '235px;'], ['height', '40px;'], ['text-align', 'center;'], ['line-height', '40px;'], ['border', '4px solid #141a20;']]
    - border: '4px solid #141a20;'
    - color: '#1d1d1d;'
    - float: 'right;'
    - height: '40px;'
    - line-height: '40px;'
    - text-align: 'center;'
    - width: '235px;'
  - refs: ['.featured_container', '.container_12', '.grid_4', 'a']
```

Using a `defaultdict(dict)` to accumulate attributes by referenced CSS object:

```
from collections import defaultdict
accum = defaultdict(dict)
for res in result:
    for name in res.refs:
        accum[name].update(res.attrs)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(accum['.container_12'])
```

Gives:

```
{'border': '4px solid #141a20;',
 'color': '#1d1d1d;',
 'float': 'right;',
 'height': '40px;',
 'line-height': '40px;',
 'margin-left': 'auto;',
 'margin-right': 'auto;',
 'text-align': 'center;',
 'width': '235px;'}
```

Comment: I tried using this exact solution, maybe I am doing something wrong, but would this be able to handle entire css files ? I am passing it as this: `temp_css_file = open(root + "/" + "style.css", "r")
            temp_css_content = temp_css_file.read()
            temp_css_file.close()
            parse_css(temp_css_content, ".container_12") `  But the problem is that both prints return empty. The only change I made was put it into a function. The file passed is valid, so the problem is not there.

Comment: I tried it for one short text and it seems to be the same : `test_text = ".container_12, .container_16 {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:960px}"
            result = parser.parseString(test_text)
            print("<---- This is the parse result --->")
            print(result.dump())` <---- This is the parse result --->
[]

Comment: The parser relies on the line-breaks as shown in your original CSS example to detect the end of each value. Your short text does not separate the key:value; elements onto separate lines.  Try `test_text = ".container_12, .container_16 {\nmargin-left:auto;\n margin-right:auto;\n width:960px\n}"`.  If you need to support multiple key:values on the same line, then you'll need to refine the definition of `attr_spec` to read just up to the next ';' or '}', instead of using `restOfLine`.

Comment: You can also try using `searchString` instead of `parseString` if you want to sift through a full CSS file looking for these. No guarantees on what other unwanted stuff this might match. This is far from a full CSS parser.

Comment: Usually the files don't have same line attributes, that was just an example of me trying to figure out why my file does not seem to work. This is one of the files I tested with it [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/WkVuB6zx) . I am reading in python as shown in my comment above. Is there any conversion I should be doing to make it work with your parser ?

Comment: The issue is that `attr_spec` uses `restOfLine`, but if there are multiple key:value's on the same line, then it looks like you would read up to but not including the next ';' or '}'. Try replacing the definition of `attr_spec` with `attr_spec =  pp.Group(attr_name("name") + COLON + pp.CharsNotIn(";{}")("value"))`. To further work this, I would define `attr_value`, rewrite `attr_spec` to be `attr_spec = pp.Group(attr_name("name") + COLON + attr_value("value"))` and then focus efforts on getting `attr_value` defined properly (being everything for a specific attribute after the ':').

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I do not fully understand how everything works with parsers, so I managed to make a simpler function to just go line by line and start adding attributes if the class name is found, unless a "}" character  is met and it seems to work ok with my files

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
\.container_12\b[^{]*{([\s\S]*?)}
```

and your desired result will be in `\1` so just iterate it and do whatever you want with it.

https://regex101.com/r/AIR8W8/1